# MATLAB .mat in Pandas DataFrame to be used in Tensorflow

Tags: pandas, matlab, tensorflow

I have gone days trying to figure this out, hopefully someone can help.

I am uploading a .mat file into python using scipy.io, placing the struct into a dataframe, which will then be used in Tensorflow.

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
import numpy as p
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import TF

path = '/home/anthony/PycharmProjects/Deep_Learning_MATLAB/circuit-data/for tinghao/template1-lib5-eqns-CR-RESULTS-SET1-FINAL.mat'

raw_data = loadmat(path, squeeze_me=True)
data = raw_data['Graphs']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=int)
df.pop('transferFunc')

print(df.dtypes)
```

The out put is:

```
A        object
Ln       object
types    object
nz        int64
np        int64
dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The struct is (43249x6). Each cell in the 'A' column is a different sized matrix, i.e. 18x18, or 16x16 etc. Each cell in "Ln" is a row of letters each in their own separate cell. Each cell in 'Types' contains 12 columns of numbers, and 'nz' and 'np' i have no issues with.

I want to put all columns into a dataframe, and use column A or LN or Types as the 'Labels' and nz and np as 'features', again i do not have issues with the latter. Can anyone help with this or have some kind of work around.

The end goal is to have tensorflow train on nz and np and give me either a matrix, Ln, or Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
raw_data = loadmat(path, squeeze_me=True)
data = raw_data['Graphs']
graph_labels = pd.DataFrame()
graph_labels['perf'] = raw_data['Objective'][0:1000]
graph_labels['np'] = data['np'][0:1000]
```

The code above helped out. Its very simple and drawn out, but it got the job done. But, it does not work in tensorflow because tensorflow does not accept this format, and that was my main issue. I have to convert adjacency matrices to networkx graphs, then upload them into stellargraph.

Answer (score 0):

What type of data is your .mat file of ? Is your application very time critical?
If you can collect all your data in a struct you could give jsonencode a try, make the struct a json file and load it back into python via json (see json documentation on loading data).

Then you can create a pandas dataframe via

```
pd.df.from_dict()
```

Of course this would only be a workaround. Still you would have to ensure your data in the MATLAB struct is correctly orderer to be then imported and transferred to a df.

Comment: I did that, and the DataFrame threw an error, stating that everything had to be the same size array. When i tried to jsonencode 1 column of data, and loaded it into python, in the DataFram it would show everything in one cell, not separated.

Comment: If you parse your data (as you correctly did, you get a dictionary anyway) by yourself and make the data lists of lists (of lists if necessary, where lists also contain np arrays) it should be working. At least I tried this like that in the shell and it worked. How about that ? There shouldn't be that big of a problem making 'A' a list of np.arrays and then pass colum names when creating the frame.